# how to change django default ForeignKey type from integer to string?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, primary-key

```
class NewStock(models.Model):
    stock_info = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    stock_xcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)

class Stock(models.Model):
    stock_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stock_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

In database,there will be a `stock_info_id` column and its type is integer. When `stock_id` starts with `0`, such as `000001`, It will be `stock_info_id=1` and will fail to get `stock_info` because `1` is not found in column `stock_id` of `Stock` table.

How can I specify an exact type for a `ForeignKey`.

For this problem, things will be good if `stock_info_id` is `CharField` other than `Integer`.

The code before changing looks like this. I just not set `stock_id` and `stock_xcode` as `primary key`. In this situation, `stock_info_id` should be `integer`.

```
class NewStock(models.Model):
    stock_info = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    stock_xcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

class Stock(models.Model):
    stock_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stock_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
```

After I make `stock_id` as `primary key`,  `makemigrations` and `migrate`,the `stock_info_id` is still `integer`.

The migration file is here.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('stockinfo', '0008_auto_20180519_1017'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='newstock',
        name='id',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='stock',
        name='id',
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='newstock',
        name='stock_xcode',
        field=models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='stock',
        name='stock_id',
        field=models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True),
    ),
]
```

The chosen db is postgresql. The `newstock` table.

```
     name      |           type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 stock_xcode   | character varying(10)    |           | not null |
 stock_info_id | integer                  |           | not null |
```

The `stock` table.

```
    name    |          type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 stock_name | character varying(200) |           | not null |
 stock_id   | character varying(10)  |           | not null |
```

Comment: Well the foreign key takes the same type as the primary key of the model it refers to. But usually it is advisable *not* to use anything else than a integer, since it will start breaking `GenericForeignKey`s.

Comment: So `stock_info_id` is a `CharField` (at the database level, and you can also query it that way).

Comment: Why the `referenced type`and `referencing type` are not the same in this situation? Had I do something wrong?

Comment: did you make migrations and migrate? What does the database says (what if you query `desc table_name`?)

Comment: can you show the code of the migrations that were constructed?

Comment: Looks to me that the migrations are not done correctly. If you build up a model from scratch, then it should work...

Comment: Yeap. Thanks for your inspiration. I fix this by resetting my database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Foreign keys do not take the same type as the primary key of the model. It takes the same type as the primary key of the current historic representation of the target model. Even with unmanaged models, which create a migration that doesn't generate SQL, it will use that representation to generate the foreign key. This is a very subtle but important distinction, because for unmanaged models only an initial migration is created and no other changes in the model will be recorded (including a change of primary key). This initial migration determines foreign key types.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this by resetting my database.

1. `python manager.py flush`
2. remove all files under `migrations` directory
3. `python manager.py makemigrations`
4. `python manager.py migrate`

The price is high when dropping a whole database. A better way is to check `migration` files and rollback to a proper state and do the `migratxxx` actions from that point.

Comment: You'll need to leave the empty "/__init/__.py" file inside the migrations folder for it to work properly. Otherwise makemigrations will not work.